# How to extract somo character after a string with a number of word which can change in R

Tags: r, string, extract, rscript

I would like to extract a couple of characters (numbers in this case), which go after a string of letters that can change their length (for instance, between 1 and 3). For example:

```
animals<-c('B02420','SS9874','MZ990122','HRB1281','NO2451068')
```

Here, I would like to obtain this:

```
digits<-c(02,98,99,12,24)
```

I don't know if it exists a simple way to get them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gsub("^[A-Z]+([0-9]{2}).*", "\\1", animals)
[1] "02" "98" "99" "12" "24"
```

explanation

`^[A-Z]+` from the start of the string a sequence of capital letters
`([0-9]{2})` capture a sequence of 2 exactly two digits to group 1
`.*` the rest
`\\1` group 1